# Custom button in lightning component and Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I am using a lightning component in a flow. The lightning component has a `Cancel` button. On click of button want to close the flow and redirect to page from where flow gets launch.
Using below code for override

```
var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
navigate("PREVIOUS");
```

but it is not working. Can someone assist here?

Comment: Is there a previous screen available or are you on the first screen (single screen flow) and is the component holding the cancel button a top level component?

Comment: There is no previous screen. From the first screen need to go back to the page from where flow has launch.

Comment: The previous event works only if you have a `previous` screen. It not a `back` button. What you are looking for is a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The previous event works only if you have a previous screen. What you are looking for is a redirection which you possibly can achieve via navigation service.

> **A screen’s available actions are determined by:** 
>   Where in the flow the screen is. For example, Previous isn't supported
>   on the first screen in a flow, Finish is supported for only the last
>   screen in a flow, and you can never have both Next and Finish.

[See here for details.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate_actions.htm)